# Why can't I find Java desktop application in Netbeans 8.0

Tags: java, netbeans, desktop-application

I downloaded Netbeans 8.0 with all bundle from http://netbeans.org/downloads and installed it successfully on Windows 8.

But I can't find Java Desktop Application which should be under Java category when add new project as 6.5 does.

Where is it? Or what is the substitute one in 8.0? I need something to create GUI by dragging components.

Thanks

Comment: Because the project behind the Desktop Application was abandoned. It would also argue that Netbeans 8 is focusing on features within Java 8, namly JavaFX 8 - but that's a massive assumption...

Answer (score 12):

You can still use Netbeans GUI components in Netbeans 8.0.

Create a normal Java Project:

1. Select "New Project" on the "File" menu.
2. Select "Java"
3. Select "Java Application"
4. Fill out the required data and finish.

Once the project is created:

1. Right click in a java package and select "New", then "Other" at the bottom of the menu.
2. Select "Swing GUI Forms"

Then choose the file type (JFrame as an example).

Netbeans will load the GUI tools for you at that moment.

Comment: Can you also give the steps for simple java desktop application with database.? It'll be helpful.  Thanks